# Can't install Yeoman's generator-webapp at Windows 10

Tags: yeoman

I'm trying to study Yeoman (trying to test it for the first time), but following the Getting started docs, **I'm not being able to install the most basic generator, the generator-webapp**.

Here's the returned messages and my npm-debug-log: http://www.filedropper.com/npm-debug

[image: Git Bash messages]

I was able to install Yeoman, Bower, Grunt and Gulp, normally and globally, but when I try the generator-web-app, it gave me those errors above. I'm already using Bower and Grunt in my projects, normally.

I'm using **Windows 10** and I'm trying to install it through **Git Bash**, running with **Administrador privileges**.

P.s.: I've already tried to run **npm cache clean**, which I saw it as a suggestion in other questions.

In advance, **thank you very much** for any interaction.

Comment: What is your Node.js and npm version (check with `node -v` and  `npm -v`)? You may try updating npm (`npm install -g npm`) and check if the error persists.

Comment: Also, try running the command with  `cmd.exe` instead of Git Bash, and without Administrator privileges.

Comment: Hello @FabrícioMatté. Both of the versions were already on the img, node's v4.1.1 and npm 2.14.4. Trying running it through cmd gave me the same results. I updated npm (now's 3.3.6) and trying to installiing generator-webapp worked! You're a genious. Really, really thank you very much. Put your comments on an answer below to get approved. Damn it, don't know how I didn't notice that... my best wishes to you! Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install a recent version of npm and it will automatically attempt to fix any permission issues:

```
npm install -g npm
```